# Writing arrays of Parcelables to a Parcel in Android

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

I'm trying to write an array of objects that implement [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) into a [Parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html) using   [writeParcelableArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeParcelableArray%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29).

The objects I'm trying to write are defined (as you'd expect) as:

```
public class Arrival implements Parcelable {
    /* All the right stuff in here... this class compiles and acts fine. */
}
```

And I'm trying to write them into a `Parcel' with:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    Arrival[] a;
    /* some stuff to populate "a" */
    dest.writeParcelableArray(a, 0);
}
```

When Eclipse tries to compile this I get the error:

> Bound mismatch: The generic method
>   writeParcelableArray(T[], int) of type
>   Parcel is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Arrival[], int). The
>   inferred type Arrival is not a valid
>   substitute for the bounded parameter
>   < T extends Parcelable >

I completely don't understand this error message. `Parcelable` is an interface (not a class) so you can't extend it. Anyone have any ideas?

**UPDATE:** I'm having basically the same problem when putting an `ArrayList` of `Parcelable`s into an `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("locations", (ArrayList<Location>) locations);
```

yields:

> The method putParcelableArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList< ? extends Parcelable >) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList< Location >)

This may be because `Location` was the class I was working on above (that wraps the `Arrival`s), but I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it just wanted me to build an array of Parcelables. To use the example from the question:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    Parcelable[] a;
    /* 
        some stuff to populate "a" with Arrival 
        objects (which implements Parcelable) 
    */
    dest.writeParcelableArray(a, 0);
}
```

Comment: As I said, declare your array using the interface. Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can extend an interface, and it looks like you need to do just that.  The generics parameter in writeParcelableArray is asking for an extended interface (not the interface itself).  Try creating an interface MyParcelable extends Parcelable.  Then declaring your array using the interface, but the impl should be your Arrival extends MyParcelable.

Answer (score -1):

I know the problem is solved but my solution was other so I'm posting it here: in my case Eclipse automatically imported wrong package because of classes names abiguity(some dom.Comment instead of my Comment class).